# c# Get variable value from Form when value changed with timer in usercontrol

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

I have a usercontrol which have timer

```
 public partial class Cumle : UserControl
 {
     private bool cond=false;

     //Some Code....

     private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //Some Code....
         if(//some condition...)
             cond=true;
     }
 }
```

I am working on windows form.I want to display a message box which shows me that cond is true.I want to make this stuff without using timer on Form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
      //What I must write here?
}
```

Comment: Can't you just make the user control show the message box?

Comment: Add an event on your `UserControl`. Subscribe to the event from `Form1`. Fire the event when `cond` is set to true.

Comment: `Cumle` can provide an event when value is changed, to which you subscribe in `Form1`.

Comment: @Baldrick I dont know how to use event if you answer I can also select as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a public event to your UserControl, and subscribe to it from your main form.

Something like this should do it:

```
public partial class Cumle : UserControl
{
   public event Action<bool> ConditionChanged = delegate {};

   private bool cond=false;

   //Some Code....

   private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Some Code....
       if(//some condition...)
       {
           cond=true;
           ConditionChanged(cond);
       }
   }
}
```

Then in your form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    void SubscribeToConditionChanged()
    {
        myUserControl.ConditionChanged += ShowDlg;
    }

    void ShowDlg(bool condition)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("....");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to write some code in delegate { }.Because this code not worked.I putted breakpoint at SubscribeToConditionChanged method in Form but not run

Comment: You need to call `SubscribeToConditionChanged` after the form's construction - I'd suggest adding the call after `InitializeComponent` in the constructor of your form.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you should use Events. I would go like this:

```
public partial class Cumle : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ConditionChangedToTrue;

    protected virtual void OnConditionChangedToTrue(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ConditionChangedToTrue != null)
            ConditionChangedToTrue(this, e != null ? e : EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some Code....
        if (true) // add your condition
        {
            cond = true;
            OnConditionChangedToTrue(null);
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Cumle cumle = new Cumle();

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       cumle.ConditionChangedToTrue+= Cumle_ConditionChangedToTrue;
    }

    private void Cumle_ConditionChangedToTrue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add your event handling code here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```